# TypeError: Cannot call method 'then' of undefined at Object.Parse.File.save

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parse-platform, promise

I am using the js api for parse.com from an Angular js app. I am trying to save / update the profile picture of the user. I've got the following code:

Some html . . .

```
<input type="file" capture="camera" accept="image/*" id="profilePhotoFileUpload">
```

Thansk to [google i/o](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EPYnGFEcis4&feature=youtube_gdata_player) and [raymond](http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2013/5/20/Capturing-camerapicture-data-without-PhoneGap) and [parse js guide](https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#files)

code in my controller:

```
$scope.updateUserProfile = function (user) {

        var fileUploadControl = $("#profilePhotoFileUpload")[0];
        if (fileUploadControl.files.length > 0) {
            var file = fileUploadControl.files[0];
            var name = "photo.jpg";

            var parseFile = new Parse.File(name, file);

            parseFile.save();


}
```

I keep getting this error:

TypeError: Cannot call method 'then' of undefined
    at Object.Parse.File.save (parse-1.2.8.js:4084:43)

[image]

when calling parseFile.save()

basically the _source is undefined . . . why?!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally work it around, since my ultimate goal was to use it with phonegap, [with the info in this post.](http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2013/7/10/Quick-note-for-Parse-and-JavaScript-Users#c0B6B2788-DF3A-3C87-ECC80849B56CC2BB) . Big thanks to Raymond Camden!

function gotPic(data) {

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(data, function(entry) {

    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
        var byteArray = new Uint8Array(evt.target.result);
        var output = new Array( byteArray.length );
        var i = 0;
        var n = output.length;
        while( i < n ) {
            output[i] = byteArray[i];
            i++;
        }                
        var parseFile = new Parse.File("mypic.jpg", output);

        parseFile.save().then(function(ob) {
                navigator.notification.alert("Got it!", null);
                console.log(JSON.stringify(ob));
            }, function(error) {
                console.log("Error");
                console.log(error);
            });

    }

    reader.onerror = function(evt) {
          console.log('read error');
          console.log(JSON.stringify(evt));
      }

    entry.file(function(s) {
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(s);
    }, function(e) {
        console.log('ee');
    });

});
```

}

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else is working Phonegap and Parse, here is another helpful example from Raymond Camden, that takes a picture:

http://www.raymondcamden.com/2013/07/23/better-example-of-phonegap-parse-and-uploading-files

```
var imagedata = "";    

$("#takePicBtn").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    navigator.camera.getPicture(gotPic, failHandler, 
        {quality:50, destinationType:navigator.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
         sourceType:navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY});
});

function gotPic(data) {
    console.log('got here');
    imagedata = data;
    $("#takePicBtn").text("Picture Taken!").button("refresh");
}
```

and it gets saved like:

```
var parseFile = new Parse.File("mypic.jpg", {base64:imagedata});
        console.log(parseFile);
            parseFile.save().then(function() {
                var note = new NoteOb();
                note.set("text",noteText);
                note.set("picture",parseFile);
                note.save(null, {
                    success:function(ob) {
                        $.mobile.changePage("#home");
                    }, error:function(e) {
                        console.log("Oh crap", e);
                    }
                });
                cleanUp();
            }, function(error) {
                console.log("Error");
                console.log(error);
            });
```

Especially note the `{base64:imagedata}`, as this is the key for creating the parse file using string data like this.